# How to get value from string javascript?

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I have this string

```
var a = toNormal("sdf45sdf4sdf45sd4f5s4df"),
b = toNormal("fg45df4g5dfg5df"),
c = toNormal("s5d4f5sd4fsdfdd5c");
... other code
```

how to get `"sdf45sdf4sdf45sd4f5s4df"`, `"fg45df4g5dfg5df"` and `"s5d4f5sd4fsdfdd5c"`?

my try

```
$pattern = '/a = toNormal("(.*)");/';
preg_match($pattern, $html, $matches);
```

Comment: `(` and `)` are special

Comment: yeah just escape the looked up parenthesis